# set row to disabled based on value put in text box and url in href in row

Tags: javascript, jquery

As part of a Chrome extension I'm trying to add a text box to a given page and any rows on that page containing the number from the text box in a URL will become disabled. The number corresponds to the players league and the idea is by filling in their league number they won't accidentally attach a league mate.

The below example disables a row containing an href with 1116 in it. What I'd like to do is have new rows disable when the value is changed. I've tried different versions of change(function(){ but, have been unable to come up with a working version. Forgive my abuse of the parent selector.

```
if (document.URL.indexOf("battle_pick.game") > -1) {
{
window.onload = function()  {
    previousInnerHTML = document.getElementById('pageHeader').innerHTML;
    previousInnerHTML = previousInnerHTML.concat("<div align=\"center\"><form style=\"display: inline\" action=\"#\" method=\"get\">"+
    "<button class=\"btn\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">&nbsp;Jump to Level&nbsp;</button>"+
    "&nbsp;<input type=\"text\" class=\"levelpicker\" size=\"4\" name=\"levelshow\" value=\"\"/></form>"+
    "&nbsp;<input title=\"Put your league number here to prevent attacking league mates\" type=\"text\" id=\"myleague\" class=\"levelpicker\" size=\"4\" name=\"myleague\" value=\"1116\"/></div>");
    document.getElementById('pageHeader').innerHTML = previousInnerHTML;

    var name2 = document.getElementById('myleague').value;
    $("a[href*="+name2+"]").parent().parent().parent().css("pointer-events", "none");
    $("a[href*="+name2+"]").parent().parent().parent().css("cursor", "default");
    $("a[href*="+name2+"]").parent().parent().parent().css("opacity", "0.5");
}
}
}
```

Comment: You for sure need to swap these two lines `if (document.URL.indexOf("battle_pick.game") > -1) {
{
window.onload = function()  {`

Comment: Also `document.getElementById('pageHeader').innerHTML += '<div align="center"....</div>';` or `$(function() { if (document.URL.indexOf("battle_pick.game") > -1) { $("#pageHeader").html(function() { return this.innerHTML+'<div....</div>' }); } })`

Comment: All of the above actually works. I'm just hoping to make it so the value for myleague is something that can be typed in rather than built into the code.